# QAction shortcut "paste" does not trigger

Tags: python, pyside2

I am writing a word processor using Pyside2 (in windows). I have a QAction for pasting and a shortcut for this action:

```
    toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
    self.addToolBar(toolbar)

    paste_action = QAction("Paste", self)
    paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Paste)
    paste_action.triggered.connect(self.fn_paste)
    toolbar.addAction(paste_action)


def fn_paste(self):
    print("pasted")
```

The expected behavior is that, when i hit ctrl + v (paste shortcut in windows) with focus on a QTextEdit, it should run fn_paste. Instead it pastes the text from the clipboard into the QTextEdit and does not run fn_paste. Same if i set

```
paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+V"))
```

But when i use some other KeySequence

```
paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+E"))
```

it does work as expected (printing "pasted" in console).

The same problem occurs with:

```
paste_sc = QShortcut(QKeySequence.Paste, self)
paste_sc.activated.connect(self.fn_paste)
```

I would guess that the system shortcut "ctrl + v" somehow overrides the application shortcut? (But i do not know).

Maybe i am missing something (i just started using QT a few days ago and am quite a noob still). So... how can i make it work?

As requested a minimal, reproducible example:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import (
    QKeySequence,
    )

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTextEdit,
    QToolBar,
    QAction,
    )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        textfield = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(textfield)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        paste_action = QAction("Paste", self)
        paste_action.setStatusTip("Paste from clipboard")
        paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Paste) #does not work
        # paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+V")) #does not work
        # paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+E")) #works but wrong shortcut
        paste_action.triggered.connect(self.fn_paste)
        toolbar.addAction(paste_action)

    def fn_paste(self):
        print("Pasted")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: minimal reproducible example added

Comment: @Koyagi the paste shortcut is automatically grabbed by the textedit as soon as it has focus, and since it's the only widget in the window, it will not be propagated to the (parent) widget. The actual question is: why do you need to override an already existing shortcut (which is widely considered a convention for paste operation)?

Comment: "and since it's the only widget in the window" - It is the only widget in the requested minimalist example, not in my project. "The actual question is: why..."  - (It is not the actual question.. at least not mine) I want it to paste text but i also need to call a function triggered by pasting text and found no possible way (beside not using the common ctrl+v for it) to do that as there is no "ontextpasted" and i cannot use "ontextchanged" because the function i want to call will alter the text and lead to an infinite loop (beside that it would call the function much more often than needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an event filter now to get the desired result. As i still try to get my head around how and why it works (i have only a rough idea, some help with explanation would be nice) take it with a grain of salt:

mre:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    QEvent
    )

from PySide2.QtGui import (
    QKeySequence,
    )

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTextEdit,
    QToolBar,
    QAction,
    )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textfield = TextField()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textfield)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        paste_action = QAction("Paste", self)
        paste_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence.Paste)
        paste_action.triggered.connect(self.fn_paste)
        toolbar.addAction(paste_action)

    def fn_paste(self):
        self.textfield.paste()
        print("Pasted")


class TextField(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.ShortcutOverride:
            return True
        return False


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```